# can't open photos on Toshiba lap top windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Photos in a folder can be viewed as a slide show only. Can't open any single pictures at all. This happened suddenly. I've updated windows which made no difference.  Help please!

Comment: You should probably explain exactly what happens why you double-click on a photo, and when you right-click on one. Also, please explain the steps you use to view them as slideshow.

Comment: thank you, but I haven't updated to windows 10

Comment: double clicking causes the wheel to turn as if it's going to open then it stops, same with right click-open......for the slide show, if the pics are in a folder the slide show is an option at the top and click on it and it opens the slide show. Great to see but no good for the editing I need to do.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to get the old Windows Photo Viewer back...

## If you still have Windows 7:

- go to **Control Panel**
- select **Default Programs**
- choose **Set Your Default Programs**
- and select **Windows Photo Viewer**

## If you upgraded your windows on Windows 10:

- open up **Settings**
- go to **System** **>>** **Default apps**
- Under **Photo viewer** you should see your current default photo viewer (probably the new Photos app). Click this to see a list of options for a new default photo viewer. Assuming you upgraded to Windows 10 from a previous version of Windows, you should be able to see Windows Photo Viewer as an option.
- choose **Windows Photo Viewer** and exit the Settings menu, and you're done - photos will now open up in Windows Photo Viewer.

[image]

## if that didn't help then continue reading...

if you are unable to choose Windows Photo Viewer from the app list, follow these simple steps:

- copy this code into Notepad and save it as **fix.reg** ... **(NOT fix.reg.txt)**

  `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll]`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell]`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open]`
  `"MuiVerb"="@photoviewer.dll,-3043"`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\command]`
  `@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\`
  `00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\`
     `6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\`
  `00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\`
  `25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\`
  `00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\`
  `6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\`
  `00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\`
  `5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\`
  `00,31,00,00,00`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\open\DropTarget]`
  `"Clsid"="{FFE2A43C-56B9-4bf5-9A79-CC6D4285608A}"`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print]`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\command]`
  `@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\`
  `00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,\`
  `6e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,20,00,22,00,25,\`
  `00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,46,00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,73,00,\`
  `25,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,73,00,20,00,50,00,68,00,6f,\`
  `00,74,00,6f,00,20,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,5c,00,50,00,68,00,\`
  `6f,00,74,00,6f,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\`
  `00,22,00,2c,00,20,00,49,00,6d,00,61,00,67,00,65,00,56,00,69,00,65,00,77,00,\`
  `5f,00,46,00,75,00,6c,00,6c,00,73,00,63,00,72,00,65,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,25,\`
  `00,31,00,00,00`
  `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\photoviewer.dll\shell\print\DropTarget]`
  `"Clsid"="{60fd46de-f830-4894-a628-6fa81bc0190d}"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.bmp]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.gif]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.ico]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jfif]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpeg]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jpg]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.png]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.tif]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.tiff]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.wdp]`
  `@="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bmp\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.gif\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ico\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpeg\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bmp\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jfif\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpeg\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.jpg\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.tif\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.tiff\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
  `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.wdp\OpenWithProgids]`
  `"PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff"=hex(0):`
- double click it to merge it
- if prompted, click on **Run**, **Yes (UAC)**, **Yes**, and **OK** to approve the merge.
- done

  ---

  ---

**Plan B**: https://imageglass.org/

Comment: thank you, but when you say Settings, where can I find it?

Comment: @Vanessa I've updated my answer, see it now

Comment: thank you! but, I had already been down that road and set it as default. and it is still set as default :( I think it's time for a new laptop

Comment: thank you all for your help, as it turns out it was my anti virus had put programs "to sleep" so yea, all good now

Comment: @Vanessa I am glad to hear that and I am sorry, that I couldnt help you.